# how to use inline javascript code to auto center pop up window

Tags: javascript

I have a in line javascript used in AJAX, would like to auto center when open, but make the change in the inline scriprt only. Is that possible? Here's my code:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' title='owner' onclick=\"window.open('owner.html','owner','height=320, width=300,location=no,scrollbars=yes')\ >some text</a>
```

Comment: "Is that possible?"  Yes it is possible.

Comment: Could you pls show me how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I worked with verisimilitude's answer and got this to work:

```
<a onclick="javascript:void window.open('http://www.google.com','1380642102467','width=400,height=300,resizable=1,left='+(screen.width/2-200)+',top='+(screen.height/2-150));return false;" href="http://www.google.com"><u>CLICK HERE</u></a>
```

The main difference was in this section:

```
left='+(screen.width/2-200)+'
top='+(screen.height/2-150)
```

I found that subtracting the difference of the window size worked if half the window size were subtracted within the (screen.) parameter. The -200 and -150 parts are calculated from half the size of my pop-up window (as manually entered in the "width" and "height"). I don't know if there is a more dynamic way to this based on varying pop-up window sizes, but I personally don't need it to do that and am fine with entering a static value.

I needed this to be completely inline as well. The place where I need to use this does not allow changing the head or adding additional files. I am restricted to upload body HTML only.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate `left` and `top` and supply the computed values as parameters to the `window.open()` call. I'm not sure why you want the JavaScript to be inline, it better be done in a separate call so that you can invoke the same function from all places.

```
Left = (screen.width / 2) - (Provided Width of the Popup / 2)
Top  = (screen.height / 2) - (Provided Height of the Popup / 2)
```

Posting only the relevant code -

```
window.open('owner.html','owner','height=320, width=300,location=no,scrollbars=yes,left=' + (screen.width/2)-(300/2) + ',top=' + (screen.height/2)-(320/2))
```

Comment: Thanks, verisimilitude, but this opens the window in large size in the center, it doesn't keep the assigned 'height' & "width"